# The order of accuracy when finding the LTE

Tags: taylor-expansion, linear-approximation, truncation-error

When finding the Local Truncation Error (LTE) of a Linear multistep method (LMM), I'm aware how to taylor expand the expression, multiply by $1/H$, and then simplify as shown below:
[image]
[image]

Now my question is what is the importance of the order of accuracy ($\mathcal{O}(h^2)$), and why does it change in the last line of this equation.

Comment: Do you know the [Bachmann–Landau notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, currently I just think that the $\mathcal{O}(h^2)$ value just represents the highest term in the final equation, which in this one is $h^2$.